# Update the value of element in 2-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I am wondering why two code segments below have different outputs. Could someone explain this?

Code 1

```
d = 5
matrix_list = [[0] * d] * d
matrix_list[0][3] = 1
for i in matrix_list:
    print(i)

Output:
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Code 2

```
matrix_list = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
matrix_list[0][3] = 1
print()
for i in matrix_list:
    print(i)

Output: 
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: print the memory location of each list by `print(id(i))` in the `for` loop. You'll notice that in Code 1, all lists are pointing to the same memory location, whereas, in Code 2 each list has been assigned different memory. So when you update in Code 1, any change in any list will be reflected in all the other lists, since internally they all are single list only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens, because lists are mutable in python and when you do as `[[0] * d] * d` you actually use the same list reference for all lists in the list.

```
list_1 = [1,2]
list_2 = list_1
list_2[0] = 3
print(list_1) -> output: [3,2]
```

It happens, because `list_1` and `list_2` are linked to the same object. You can check with:

```
print(id(list_1))
print(id(list_2))
```

Or in your case you can try printing ids instead of value:

```
for i in matrix_list:
    print(id(i))
```

It means the correct way to create list of lists in your case is:

```
list_of_lists = []
for i in range(5):
    list_of_lists.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

It will create a new list object on every iteration.